# How to correctly use types with FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, types, formarray, formgroups

How should I declare this type ?

Let say I've a `FormGroup`

1. I instantize it in the constructor.

```js
export interface MyType {
 myValue: string
}
```

```js
myForm: FormGroup
myArray: FormArray // <FormControl<MyType>>

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    myArray: this._formBuilder.array([])
  })
}
```

2. Because I have somewhere a button that let me add a new element to the array, I do as follow

```js
addElement() {
  this.myArray = this.myForm.get('myArray') as unknown as FormArray

  this.myArray.push(this.newElement())
}

private _newElement(): FormGroup { // What type to use ? 
  return this._formBuilder.group({
     myValue: ''
  })
}
```

But when I do use the

```js
myArray: FormArray<FormControl<MyType>>
```

I get the following error

```
Argument of type 'FormGroup<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl<MyType>'.
  Type 'FormGroup<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormControl<MyType>': defaultValue, registerOnChange, registerOnDisabledChange
```

Somebody knows

- which type I should here `private _newElement(): FormGroup { // What type to use ?`
  or
- Is this correct `myArray: FormArray<FormControl<MyType>>`? *-> `FormGroup<FormControl<MyType>>` being incorrect*

Comment: Having the same issu,e not much documentation on it out there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Declare the interface/class for the Typed Form.

```
export class MyTypeForm {
  myValue: FormControl<string>;
}
```

2. Declare `myArray` type as `FormArray<FormGroup<MyTypeForm>>`.

```
myArray: FormArray<FormGroup<MyTypeForm>>;
```

3. The `_newElement` method to return `FormGroup<MyTypeForm>` type.

```
private _newElement(): FormGroup<MyTypeForm> {
  return this._formBuilder.group<MyTypeForm>({
    myValue: this._formBuilder.control(''),
  });
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ig24ug?file=src/main.ts)

Reference: [Angular Strictly Typed Forms (Complete Guide)](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/)

Comment: Thx, just a little question, but the `MyType` interface does already exists and I will like to use it directly instead of having to recreated a new class. Is this possible or is your answer the only way?

Comment: You can create generic interface that defines each property as FormControl like `export type FormControlType<T> = {[key in keyof T]: FormControl<T[key]>}`. But it's not always usable, i.e. if some property is object, it will define FormControl with object as value (and it's OK), but maybe you wanted nested FormGroup instead.

Comment: Hi @RaphaëlBalet, I think that it is needed to create another interface specified for the FormGroup, not possible to use `MyType` interface in `FormGroup` as the compiler will complain the error. I think Edmunds' comment is useful as what he mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it via inference without declaring extra types. For clarity, I'm using functions to instantiate a new form, but it could be done inline as well.

Your component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  form = this.newForm();

  constructor(
    private readonly fb: NonNullableFormBuilder,
  ) {}
```

The dateRanges field is a FormArray. The empty array passed to fb.array() is strongly-typed using a mapping function:

```
  newForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      year: this.fb.control({ value: this.current?.year ?? 2022, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
      active: [this.current?.active, [Validators.required]],
      dateRanges: this.fb.array([].map(this.newDateRangesForm)),
    });
  }
```

The mapping function for each item in the FormArray:

```
  newDateRangesForm(range: DateRange) {
    return this.fb.group({
      startDate: [range.startDate, [Validators.required]],
      endDate: [range.endDate, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }
```

Which yields a strongly typed form value:

```
const formValue = this.form.getRawValue();
```

[image]

Comment: I won't have time to implement it, but it looks like a really good solution, can someboy test it out and tell me if this should be the accepted answer ?