# Angular Typed Forms - Array of Forms in Form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to use strict typing for my form using angular 15.1.0. It contains a list of additional travelers. What i want is something like this:

```
startForm: FormGroup<StartForm>;
additionalTravelers: FormGroup<TravelerForm>[] = [];
```

but this does not work. What i now have is this:

```
additionalTravelers: FormArray<TravelerFormGroup> =
    new FormArray<TravelerFormGroup>([]);
```

with

```
export class TravelerFormGroup extends FormGroup {
```

but with this i can not type the TravelerFormGroup because i get an error here:

```
<form [formGroup]="travelerForm">
```

Type 'TravelerFormGroup' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup'.
Types of property 'controls' are incompatible.
Type 'TravelerMasterForm' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'TravelerMasterForm'.

Am I on the right pass using FormArray here? How to keep type safety then? I am confused.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `FormArray` is correct. You should specify like this:

```js
interface Traveler {
  name: FormControl<string>;
  age: FormControl<number>;
}

form = new FormGroup({
  additionalTravelers: new FormArray<FormGroup<Traveler>>([]),
});
```

The main take-away here is that the types you specify for form controls should themselves be form controls, not just values. For example, if you have a model for a form like this:

```js
type MyModel = {
  foo: number;
  bars: {
    hello: string;
  }[];
  stuff: string[];
}
```

Then you would type the corresponding `FormGroup` like this:

```js
type MyModelFormGroup = FormGroup<{
  foo: FormControl<number>;
  bars: FormArray<FormGroup<{
    hello: FormControl<string>;
  }>>;
  stuff: FormArray<FormControl<string>>;
}>;
```

Comment: thanks, that was the hint i needed

Comment: You can also do it via inference without having to declare extra interfaces. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530825/how-to-correctly-use-types-with-formarray-in-angular/77834849#77834849